# How can I have a sticky/fixed navbar that hides div above it when scrolling down the page?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When at the top of the page, I want to list the phone number and email above the navbar. However, when you start to scroll down, I want the phone number and email to go away and just show the navbar. I have tried using fixed-top, however, it always hides the phone/email.

How can I achieve this across all device sizes?

I'm using Bootstrap 4.

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">

    <header>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="float-right mt-1">
                <a href="mailto:info@example.com" class="ml-4 text-dark"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i><span class="ml-1 text-dark d-none d-sm-inline">info@example.com</span></a>
                <a href="tel:1-555-555-5555" class="ml-4 text-dark"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i><span class="ml-1 d-none d-sm-inline">+1 (555) 555-5555</span></a>
            </div>

            <br>

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-white mt-1">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Example</a>
            </nav>

        </div>

    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the .sticky-top class to just the nav element and when you scroll past it on the page it should be the only item at the top.

```
<nav class="sticky-top navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-white mt-1">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Example</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: I added sticky-top and it did nothing. The entire header section ends up going away when scrolling.

Comment: Oh yeah, the sticky element will be stuck inside the header element so you have to move it outside of that or remove the header element. You most likely want the parent element to be the body, something along those lines.